# Basic high school physics question, on measuring voltage from CRO screen:

Tags: experimental-physics

My textbook says 'this represents a voltage that varies from +300mV to -300mV. If this voltage were measured using a meter a value less than this would be displayed since the meter gives an average value of the voltage.' 
Does this mean that the meter would read 0V?

Comment: First, what is a CRO screen?  Always define acronyms when you use them.  Secondly, there are different kinds of average.  You say the voltage varies.  Is it a chaotic variation, or is it regular and periodic?

Comment: Cathode Ray Oscilloscope

Answer (score 1):

The meter will give a value less than what?  Less than +300mV or less than -300mV?

What voltage reading the meter gives depends on what type it is and what setting is used.  Perhaps the book is suggesting that the meter is on an AC setting and will show the RMS voltage.  This is $\frac{300}{\sqrt2} mV$ for a sinusoidal waveform, which is less than the peak voltage of $300mV$.  If the waveform is not sinusoidal, the RMS value will be different.

If the meter is set to DC and the voltage varies symmetrically about $0V$ then the meter might show the mean voltage of $0V$, or it might be unable to determine a value.